# Через какое событие лучше всего запускать скрипты

Tags: javascript

Через какое событие лучше всего запускать скрипты
window.onload, через jQuery или через что?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){...}, false);
// не кроссбраузерно
```

Comment: @AlexWindHope, вот точно, я просто забыл его)